# Docker volume backup and restore

Tags: backup, docker

I'm using Docker to deploy some services on a CentOS 6.4 server, and I'm trying to figure out how to properly backup data they generate.

For example, one of the services is a web application where users can upload files. For this container, I have a `/files` volume which I want to backup. Host mounts looks like they are somewhat frowned upon, because such mount is in no way portable — as said in [this blog post](http://crosbymichael.com/advanced-docker-volumes.html) and the [docker documentation for volumes](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/).

I know from the same blog post that I don't *need* a host mount to access the files in a volume, I can use `docker inspect` to find out where the files are.

But here's my problem: I was thinking about backing up just the dockerfiles needed to build the containers and the volumes associated with them. In the likely event that I have to restore everything from the backup, how would I go about knowing which volume directory corresponds to which container? Rebuilding the container causes the id and the volume path to change, so I would need some extra information to match them. What else, if anything, should I backup to be able to actually restore everything?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're right. Since you can have multiple containers with volumes on their own, you need to keep track which volume corresponds to which container.
How to do that depends on your setup: I use the name -data for the data container, so it's obvious to which container a image belongs. That way it can be backed up like this:

```
VOLUME=`docker inspect $NAME-data | jq '.[0].Volumes["/path/in/container"]'`
tar -C $VOLUME . -czvf $NAME.tar.gz
```

Now you just need to rebuild your image and recreate your data container:

```
cat $NAME.tar.gz | docker run -name $NAME-data -v /path/in/container \
                              -i busybox tar -C /path/int/container -xzf -
```

So this means you need to backup:

- Dockerfile
- volume
- volume path in container
- name of the container the volume belongs to

**Update:** In the meanwhile I created a tool to backup containers and their volume(s) (container(s)): https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-backup and a backup image that can create backups and push them to s3: https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-lloyd

Comment: That's a fair compromise, thanks. Is there a clear advantage of using a separate container for data?

Comment: This again really depends on your setup. It make sense to use a data container because you can easily refer to it by using 'volumes-from' and have all the internals abstracted away: You just attach volumes from container to other containers instead of thinking in terms of path and mount points.

Comment: I have this error invalid option -- z. It seems that the default tar in busybox doesn't support this.

Comment: jq is very cool, but rather than introducing a dependency, why not use `docker inspect`s built in templating like so:  `VOLUME=$( docker inspect -f '{{index .Volumes "/path/in/container"}}' "${NAME}-data" )`.  It's probably also wise to remind people not to expect to back up files this way while they are actively in use (e.g. databases).

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about [jq](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/jq.1.html)!

Comment: In Docker 1.8  the format has changed — `Volumes` are gone and there are `Mounts` instead with different structure. We need to do a little bit more work with `range` to find the mount point we are interested in `VOLUME=$(docker inspect --format '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ if eq .Destination "/path/in/container" }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}{{ end }}' "${NAME}-data")`

Answer (score 8):

In newer Docker (tested in `1.9.1, build 9894698`) you can use the [`cp` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

Here is an example how to copy a directory from the container to the host:

```
docker cp wordpress:/var/www/html backups/wordpress.`date +"%Y%m%d"`/
```

Here is an example how to copy a directory from the container to a `tar` file:

```
docker cp wordpress:/var/www/html - > backups/wordpress.`date +"%Y%m%d"`.tar
```

Last but not least an example how to copy a directory from the container to a `tar.gz` file:

```
docker cp wordpress:/var/www/html - | gzip > backups/wordpress.`date +"%Y%m%d"`.tar.gz
```

Comment: `docker cp` sends everything over the network. It's something you want to avoid especially if your Docker volume is already a btrfs volume.

Comment: The question mentions backup and **restore**. A restore example in this answer using `docker cp` would be nice.